# How to declare and use global external variable across multiple source files?

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

I want a global variable (object) that I can easily access whenever and wherever I wish. The problem is that my source code has multiple *.hpp **and** *.cpp files that share the same variable! I've searched and found similar questions here but somehow they didn't solve my problem.

- **With** keyword **extern** there are undefined reference errors
- **Without** keyword **extern** there are multiple definition errors
- **With** keyword **extern** and re-declarations in **all** *.cpp files *.cpp file without keyword **extern** there are multiple definition errors
- **With** keyword **extern** and re-declaration in **only one** *.cpp file without keyword **extern** the variables work fine only in that *.cpp file

*GameStateManager.hpp*

```
/// GLOBAL VARIABLES
extern sf::RenderWindow window;
extern sf::Event         event;

/// GAME STATES
#include "LogoState.hpp"

class GameStateManager
{
    ...blah blah blah...
};
```

*GameStateManager.cpp*

```
GameStateManager::GameStateManager()
{
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), TITLE, FLAGS);
    window.setFramerateLimit(FPS);
    gamestatescontainer.emplace_back(new LogoState);
}
```

*LogoState.cpp*

```
ListOfGameStates LogoState::run()
{
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.waitEvent(event);
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
    }
    return ListOfGameStates::STATE_EXIT;
}
```

Please, help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you **have** to use global scope?  In that case you can do this:

In `<Common.h>`

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_DEFINED_HERE
extern
#endif
int myGlobal;
```

In one cpp file, `<SomeFile.cpp>` do this:

```
#define GLOBAL_DEFINED_HERE 1
#include  <Common.h>
```

Everywhere else simply do

```
#include  <Common.h>
```

This approach is not pretty and is hacky, but it will work.  Be careful to define `GLOBAL_DEFINED_HERE` only once.  Alternatively, why not have a class with a static member variable?  Or even singleton, if that's your cup of tea?

Comment: This looks simpler than [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28297451/711006) but it gets you on the way to [“shoot yourself in the foot”](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#really-say-that). @MariusMacijauskas Have you tried to define multiple variables in this way? And to define them in multiple header files? Larger projects can consist of several libraries, so there would be painful to maintain one place for global variables.

Comment: Of course you can shoot yourself in the foot with this!  In modern C++ there is really no need to declare global variables - one can use static variables / functions, if that's what one wants...  Better to avoid those as well, if possible

Answer (score 1):

By declaring variable extern, you say to the compiler that there will eventually exist such variable with such name and type, but you don't want him to define it yet, so he just declares the variable.

Therefore, you also need to define the variable(without the extern keyword) somewhere, and I suggest doing that in GameStateManager.cpp since they are declared in GameStateManager.hpp.

Edit: With this, however you also need to include GameStateManager.hpp inside LogoState.cpp. If you do not want to do that, you can just write the same declaration for variables(`extern sf::RenderWindow window;` and `extern sf::Event         event;`, and it should work properly too, if you instantiate them somewhere eventually.

Comment: The even simpler solution is to create a master header "GlobalStuff.hpp", as Andre said